# Авторизация и парсинг сайта с ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, парсер

Всем привет!

Сразу к сути.
Есть сайт, в котором нужно авторизоваться и затем получать данные (json).
Логиниться хочу примерно как описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183703/using-webclient-or-webrequest-to-login-to-a-website-and-access-data). И далее примерно также получать данные.

Получить json и авторизоваться не получается, так как ссылки запросов имеют вид: https:/www.site.com/authorization/checkLoginAndPswd/?**0.46382911719324094**

Эти цифры генерируются, как я понял на стороне сервера.
IE (WebControl) сайт не поддерживает.

Как быть?

Comment: Всё указывает на то, что это просто результат джаваскриптового `Math.random()` который ни на что не влияет

Comment: А сайт указать есть возможность? Ну а вообще, смотрите что требует страница с JSON, обычно это либо ключ, либо куки, либо еще какая то информация. Узнав что именно требуется - начинаете поиск от куда эта информация берется, ну и эмулируете запросы что бы получить эту информацию.

Comment: @andreymal, если убрать ?0.46382911719324094, то выдает ошибку 404.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, https://etp.armtek.ru/

Comment: Что с цифрами, что без - одно и тоже будете получать, 404, ибо отправляется POST запрос, а не GET.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, при авторизации в Fiddler показывает, что выполняется POST запрос на указанный адрес (точнее на подобный адрес).